# Determine whether the given series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n!}$$

The task is to investigate if this series converges or diverges. I know that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}$ is infinity or a non-real number, then it diverges, otherwise it converges.

I can simply look at the expression and conclude that the sum of $1*2*3*4*5*6*...*n$ will grow faster than $ 3*3*3*3*3*...$ And therefore I know that the expression $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ is moving towards 0, the serial will therefore be convergent.

I am not shure that this calculation is valid enough. Do I have to calculate this in some other way or is this answer enough?

Comment: Try to use the ratio test in order to determine whether the series converges. It should be the easiest test to use. Unless you are asking whether the sequence converges, which then your answer will be correct

Comment: You need to be more precise. Try to show that the $n$'th term is bounded above by ${9\over (n-1)(n-1)}\cdot {3\over2}$ for $n>4$. Then use the Comparison test.

Comment: Not that is *not* sufficient to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3^n}{n!} = 0$! (Compare with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$)

Comment: I assume, from the question, that theva does not know the ratio test, nor any comparison tests.  She only vaguely knows what convergence of a series means.

Comment: You have a *series*, not a *serial*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me make some points:

- For a series $\sum{a_n}$ to converge(or exist) then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=0$. And if the value of the limit is any other real number other that zero or the limit does not exist the series diverges. Also this does not mean that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n}=0$ implies that the series converges, for ex: consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac1n}$.
- You are right in your analysis that the denominator of the fraction $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ grows faster than the denominator and hence $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n}=0$, but as you can see from my previous point this does not imply that the sum of the sequence converges.

---

As I think you might are more familiar with convergence of sequences( as you predicted that $\frac{3^n}{n!}$ converges). Let us see how we can analyze this series as a sequence.

Consider a sequence $p_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{3^n}{n!}}$. Here $p_n$ is also known as partial sum of the series, it is easy to prove that $p_n$ converges if and only if $\sum{\frac{3^n}{n!}}$ converges.

Denoting $a_n=\frac{3^n}{n!}$, note that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}=0$.

So what does that mean?. We can say that for every $1>\varepsilon>0$(Although for every $\varepsilon>0$ there should exist a $\delta$, I am additionally imposing the condition $\varepsilon <1$ for reasons you will see in a moment) there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$ , $a_{n+1}<\varepsilon \cdot a_n$.

Now as terms are finite let $k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}{a_n}$ for  $n>N$, $$p_n=k+a_N\left(1+\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2+\cdots+\varepsilon^{n-N}\right)<k+a_N\left(1+\varepsilon+\varepsilon^2+ \cdots  \right)=k+\frac{a_N}{1-\varepsilon}$$

Now this proves that $p_n$ is bounded(bounded by $k+\frac{a_N}{1-\varepsilon}$), now $p_n$ also has an interesting property that $p_n$ is monotonically increasing which means that $p_{n+1}>p_n$ (as every term of the series is positive). So as you might be expecting a bounded monotonic sequence converges (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)).

Hence $p_n$ convergence implies the series converges.

---

In the previous section, I wrote a descriptive proof although this can be done using something known as [ratio-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), which unfortunately you might be unfamiliar with, so I have illustrated a specific proof of the ratio-test here, if you are following it I recommend you study ratio test and the proof must be looking easier now.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the power expansion of exponential function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), i.e., 
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
You notice a big "resemblance". Yes, in fact
$$e^3=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n}{n!}$$
Clearly then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n}{n!}=e^3-1.$$

Comment: Nice to see you here ! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test shows that 
$$
\frac{3^{n+1} / (n+1)^{n+1}}{3^n/n^n}=3\frac{n!}{(n+1)!} <1 \text{ for $n>2$}
$$
 hence it converges... to a interesting [value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e83s62gd63c).

Comment: The fact that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3^n}{n!} = 0$ does *not* imply that the series converges!

Comment: Yes, take for example, the sequence $a_n=\frac1n$

Comment: But the series $\sum\frac{3^n}{n^n}$ converges, right?

Comment: @V.C.: Yes, but for a different reason than given.

Comment: @Keba I agree. The answer should be corrected, but it has a good idea.

Comment: Anything till "and the ratio test …" is still not important at all.

Comment: @keba you are right...